# Let P and Q be any propositions, show that $(P \wedge Q) \Rightarrow (P \Rightarrow Q) \equiv [P \wedge (P \Rightarrow Q)] \Rightarrow Q.$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

For phone users,

$(P \wedge Q) \Rightarrow (P \Rightarrow Q) \equiv [P \wedge (P \Rightarrow Q)] \Rightarrow Q$

Can you prove it for me? My friend asked me last night (GMT+7) and I still cannot solve it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both tautologies, and this can be observed with a truth table. The following is a proof via natural deduction:

---

$(p \wedge q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$

$\Leftrightarrow \neg (p \wedge q) \vee (\neg p \vee q)$ implication

$\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee \neg q \vee \neg p \vee q$ DeMorgan's Rule

$\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee \neg p \vee \neg q \vee q$ commutivity

$\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee \neg q \vee q$ idempotence

$\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee T$ negation law

$\Leftrightarrow T$ domination law

---

$[p \wedge (p \rightarrow q)] \rightarrow q$

$\Leftrightarrow \neg [p \wedge (\neg p \vee q)] \vee q$ implication

$\Leftrightarrow [\neg p \vee \neg(\neg p \vee q)] \vee q$ DeMorgan's Rule

$\Leftrightarrow [\neg p \vee (\neg \neg p \wedge \neg q)] \vee q$ DeMorgan's Rule

$\Leftrightarrow [\neg p \vee (p \wedge \neg q)] \vee q$ Double negation

$\Leftrightarrow [(\neg p \vee p) \wedge (\neg p \vee \neg q)] \vee q$ distribution

$\Leftrightarrow [T \wedge (\neg p \vee \neg q)] \vee q$ negation law

$\Leftrightarrow (\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee q$ identity law

$\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee (\neg q \vee q)$ associativity

$\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee T$ negation law

$\Leftrightarrow T$ domination law

Comment: Thank you, sir :)

Comment: No problem. If you're satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a natural deduction proof.